# Expression la plus appropriée pour remplacer « cloud-based » et « cloud-computing »

Tags: anglais, choix-de-mot, informatique, terminologie

En anglais, on parle souvent, et de plus en plus, de services qui sont dit « cloud-based » ou qui font du « cloud computing ».

Je suis en train de refaire mon CV et cherche une  expression française plus appropriée que cet affreux anglicisme! ([Que même Wikipédia propose...](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing))

Quelle serait donc l'expression la plus appropriée pour remplacer soit

> Cloud-based service

soit encore

> Cloud computing

Autour de moi, où je fais mon stage, tout le monde utilise l'expression anglaise, puisque tout le monde se comprend, mais pour mettre à jour un CV, il vaut mieux une expression française!

Comment: Ce que tu appelles un affreux anglicisme est juste une technologie sur laquelle les pontes de l'académie française n'ont pas encore pris la peine de se pencher pour trouver une expression en français vaguement approchante. Certains mots sont simplement intraduisibles, quoi qu'on en dise...

Comment: néologisme aléatoire du jour: le ouate. Il reprend l'aspect cotonneux du nuage pour former un terme péjoratif par retro-anglicisme 'j'ai encore perdu mon serveur dans le ouate'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les expressions que j'ai entendues le plus souvent sont « informatique en nuage » et « nuage informatique ». Ces expressions sont également suggérées par l'Office québécois de la langue française. D'ailleurs, l'OQLF énumère, dans sa [fiche sur le *cloud computing*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26501384), les expressions suivantes :

- Infonuagique
- Informatique intranuage
- Informatique nuagière
- Informatique en nuage
- Nuage informatique

L'Office mentionne que le terme « infonuagique » a été créé sur le modèle de « infogérance » à partir des mots « informatique » et « nuagique » et peut être utilisé également comme adjectif.

La fiche de [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&srchtxt=CLOUD%20COMPUTING&i=1&index=ent&mode=preventries&trm=CLOUD%20COLLISION%20WARNING%20SYSTEM&pos=b) (la base de données terminologiques et linguistiques du gouvernement du Canada), quant à elle, n'accorde la mention *correct* qu'aux termes « infonuagique » et « informatique en nuage ».

Je serais portée à recommander l'usage de « informatique en nuage » pour traduire *cloud computing*, mais l'usage de « nuage informatique » lorsque l'on utiliserait l'ellipse *the cloud*.

Comment: C'est marrant de voir la différence entre la France et le Québec car les termes que tu cites, on ne les entend jamais en France. Personnellement étant français et vivant en France, j'entendrais les termes que tu cites, je ne les comprendrais pas.

Comment: @Zistoloen personnellement, je vis au Québec et je n'ai jamais entendu ces termes non plus! Tout le monde utilise les termes anglais!

Comment: Kareen je dois te dire bravo pour les sources trouvées! J'imagine que ces mots ont étés créés, mais ne sont jamais entrés dans le vocabulaire courant!

Comment: Pour appuyer ces termes, je crois que l'Université de Sherbrooke (cefti) offre des cours sur l'infonuagique.

Answer (score 5):

Personnellement, je pense que les futurs recruteurs comprendraient plus facilement le terme anglais qu'une traduction française. En effet le terme *Cloud computing* est de plus en plus utilisé dans le monde de l'informatique et on ne le traduit pas forcément.

Cependant, voici quelques idées de traductions françaises :

- hébergement dans les nuages
- hébergement externalisé
- l'informatique dans les nuages (sûrement le plus usité)
- services informatiques hébergés

De plus, je pense que le terme *Cloud computing* serait mieux compris que *Cloud-based services*.

Comment: Je ne sais pas pourquoi, j'aurais tendance à mettre nuage au singulier.

Comment: @mouviciel: peut être lorsqu'on parle de _Cloud_ ? Les nuages faisant référence aux serveurs ou à quelque chose d'abstrait pour certains, je pense que le pluriel est plus approprié lorsqu'on parle de _Cloud computing_.

Comment: Je resterai également sur les termes anglais, surtout si ton CV concerne l'informatique (et non pas une sorte de hobby/passion/expérience pour un autre univers). L'informatique étant un domaine où l'anglais est utilisé à 99%, les termes anglais sont en général bien mieux compris et utilisés. De plus, certaines traductions françaises me laissent perplexes... Comme FTTH, Hashtag, etc. De plus, les traductions françaises étant tardives, si tu ne fais pas de vulgarisation, pas de soucis, ton employeur doit au minimum comprendre les concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Moi, pour combattre cet anglicisme, j'utilise « Nuagel ».
En effet, n'est-il pas logique d'associer nuage à électronique ?

Answer (score 0):

J'ai aussi utilisé "l'informatique dans les nuages" quand je traduisais un article technique pendant ma licence.

Answer (score 0):

Je dirais ***le Nuage***, méritant une majuscule, comme *la Terre* et *la Toile*, vu leur immensité.

Et de là il sera simple d'arriver à ***en/au Nuage*** pour traduire *cloud-based*. Par exemple *service en/au Nuage*.

Rien n'est plus laid que *infonuagique* et autres créations de ce genre.

Answer (score 0):

Maintenant, plusieurs utilisent nuagique au Québec pour cloud computing. Si encore inusité en France pourquoi ne pas utiliser nuagique avec l'anglais entre parenthèses?

Answer (score 0):

Au lieux d’*infonuagique* je serais plutôt tenté par *infonimbique* de [*nimbus* (*-ī*)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nimbus).

Answer (score 0):

Infonuagique me semble horrible comme terme, même s'il semble être accepté par la majorité des gens. Je préfère personnellement **informatique en nuage**. C'est assez descriptif, et bien plus poétique.